# Explicitly Display Newlines with grep

Tags: linux, grep

Is there a way to get `grep` to display the newlines in a file in a human-readable way, for example, in the way `vim` displays end-of-line characters as `$` with `:set list`?

I'm trying to describe how dot (`.`) works in a regular expression. As an initial illustration, I search for a pattern of only dot, e.g., `grep --color=auto '.' HBB.fna` (image). With the `--color` option, every character in the file is displayed in the match color in the output. However, I would like to explicitly display the end-of-line characters to show they are *not* matched. Because I am talking about `grep`, I don't want to use anything other than it.

Example output is in the attached. Again, what I'm going for is for end-of-line characters to appear at the end of every line, not in the match color.

Any help would be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: maybe the example you presented has no EOL characters

Comment: @jsotola, and how would grep decide how to print the lines then

Comment: @mark, I don't think you can do that with `grep`. It implicitly considers only the part of the line before the newline, and doesn't try to match the regex pattern against it. So it never matches, there's no question about it, so no reason to show it. (And, well, grep would print the trailing newline even if it _isn't_ there, e.g. `printf 'foo' |grep .` prints `foo<newline>` in all systems I have.)

Comment: Won't it be simple enough to pipe the output of `grep` to `cat -A`?

Comment: @unxnut And then pipe to `sed 's/\$$/\\n/'` di differentiate a EOL `$` from other instances.

Comment: `printf 'XY\n' | grep --color=always . | cat -A` will show you the color is set before and is reset after `X`, and separately before and after `Y`, but not before and after the newline.

Comment: My own preference for checking non-printing characters in a file is `od -a`.  It uses dual-character names like `sp`, `ht`, `cr`, and `nl` for the common whitespace characters, and they're easy to distinguish from the file's ordinary characters.

Comment: Thanks, everyone, for all the comments. Very helpful!

Perhaps my understanding of the way 'grep' interprets dot has been incorrect: instead of describing dot as matching any character except newline, it sounds like that with `grep`, dot matches any character, as per @ilkkachu `grep` only considers the part of the line before the newline.

Comment: @MarkPauley, well, I'd rather say that it's just that matching against the newline doesn't really come into play with regular grep. The underlying regex engine might let the dot match the newline, or not (or there might be an option), but if grep never passes one, it doesn't matter. But it's different with e.g. `grep -z` in GNU grep, which makes it take the NUL byte as the "line" separator instead of newline. `printf 'foo\nbar\0' | grep -oz 'o.b'` prints `o<newline>b` in my system, so the dot does match against the newline. Not that it helps you here, I think.

Answer (score 1):

I thought about using `cat -A` to postprocess the printout from `grep`, it'd add the `$` to mark the end of line, but would also break down the escape codes for colors.

But, at least the GNU coreutils `cat` has `cat -E`, which only marks line ends, so you'd get e.g.

```
$ printf 'foo\nbar\n' | grep --color=always . | cat -E
foo$
bar$
```

with the `$` signs not colored.

Or do it manually with Perl, this would replace the newline characters with `<NL>`:

```
$ printf 'foo\nbar\n' | grep --color=always . | perl -pe 's/\n/<NL>/'; echo
foo<NL>bar<NL>
```

similarly, the `<NL>` parts come without coloring.

With `grep -z`, the newlines would be colored, showing that the `.` does match the newline, at least in NUL-separated mode.

The same in color:

[image]

(With `grep .` as above, GNU grep prints the color-changing escapes before and after each individual character, i.e. at the start and end of each match instance. You could change to e.g. `grep '..*'` to match longer sequences in one go and get fewer escapes within the output.)

Answer (score 0):

It would be easier for everyone if the text used were posted, instead of an image.
To help everyone, here is the file (found parts of somewhere in the internet):

```
$ cat HBB.fna
>NM_000518.5 Homo sapiens hemoglobin subunit beta (HBB), mRNA
ACATTTGCTTCTGACACAACTGTGTTCACTAGCAACCTCAAACAGACACCATGGTGCATCTGACTCCTGA
GGAGAAGTCTGCCGTTACTGCCCTGTGGGGCAAGGTGAACGTGGATGAAGTTGGTGGTGAGGCCCTGGGC
AGGCTGCTGGTGGTCTACCCTTGGACCCAGAGGTTCTTTGAGTCCTTTGGGGATCTGTCCACTCCTGATG
CTGTTATGGGCAACCCTAAGGTGAAGGCTCATGGCAAGAAAGTGCTCGGTGCCTTTAGTGATGGCCTGGC
TCACCTGGACAACCTCAAGGGCACCTTTGCCACACTGAGTGAGCTGCACTGTGACAAGCTGCACGTGGAT
CCTGAGAACTTCAGGCTCCTGGGCAACGTGCTGGTCTGTGTGCTGGCCCATCACTTTGGCAAAGAATTCA
CCCCACCAGTGCAGGCTGCCTATCAGAAAGTGGTGGCTGGTGTGGCTAATGCCCTGGCCCACAAGTATCA
CTAAGCTCGCTTTCTTGCTGTCCAATTTCTATTAAAGGTTCCTTTGTTCCCTAAGTCCAACTACTAAACT
GGGGGATATTATGAAGGGCCTTGAGCATCTGGATTCTGCCTAATAAAAAACATTTATTTTCATTGCAA
```

Then, your question:

> I'm trying to describe how dot (.) works in a regular expression.

There is no simple way to match a newline in grep with a `dot` (`.`). It can be hinted by what we see:

[image]

The matched characters have to be a multiple of 3 dots, that is 69 and that leave just 1 that doesn't match the dots. That's why there is a non-colored last character in most of the lines.

But even if we were to use 71 dots (because 71 is prime there is no other number to match it). That's the 70 characters we see in each line plus an ending newline.

[image]

Because the `.` `dot` can not match a newline. it is removed before each line is processed and reattached after the line has been processed. There is no newline to match in any case.

Even if we were to use the non-standard `-z` option (which process the whole text input as one continuous block and therefore allows newlines to remain in the matched text, the newline turns out to be a non-printing character, much like an `space` or a `tab` or some other `whitespace`, the terminal can not print them.
[image]

So, we need to transform the newlines (matched or not, but present on the output) to something visible (lets use a `=`, similar to the `$` encoding of vi or `sed -n l`) and lets add an additional newline so that lines don't collapse into a continuous (without format) stream of characters. That is easy to do with `sed -z 's/\n/=\n'` or some other similar editor:
[image]

So, There is no way to match a newline with a `dot` (`.`) in grep, not even in default pcre. But we can make the newlines appear and be seen by intelligently editing the grep output.

Hope that solves your need.